# How to install cv_bridge on Windows - Ros2 Iron?

Tags: installation, cv-bridge, windows10, ros-iron

It seems the library cv_bridge is not available with [Ros2_Iron](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/releases/tag/release-iron-20231120) on Windows. So what I did I checked out the repository from [open-vision](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv) and I run the following command:

```
colcon build --packages-select cv_bridge --event-handlers console_direct+ --symlink-install
```

This what I get:

```
Starting >>> cv_bridge
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30152.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30152.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found ament_cmake_ros: 0.11.2 (C:/dev/ros/iron/share/ament_cmake_ros/cmake)
-- Found Python3: C:/Python38/python.exe (found version "3.8.3") found components: Interpreter
-- Override CMake install command with custom implementation using symlinks instead of copying resources
-- Found Python3: optimized;C:/Python38/libs/python38.lib;debug;C:/Python38/libs/python38_d.lib (found version "3.8.3") found components: Development NumPy Interpreter Development.Module Development.Embed
-- Found Boost: C:/Boost/boost_1_76_0 (found version "1.76.0") found components: python38
-- Found rclcpp: 21.0.2 (C:/dev/ros/iron/share/rclcpp/cmake)
-- Found rosidl_generator_c: 4.0.1 (C:/dev/ros/iron/share/rosidl_generator_c/cmake)
-- Found rosidl_generator_cpp: 4.0.1 (C:/dev/ros/iron/share/rosidl_generator_cpp/cmake)
-- Using all available rosidl_typesupport_c: rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c;rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c
-- Using all available rosidl_typesupport_cpp: rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp;rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp
-- Found rmw_implementation_cmake: 7.1.0 (C:/dev/ros/iron/share/rmw_implementation_cmake/cmake)
-- Found rmw_fastrtps_cpp: 7.1.1 (C:/dev/ros/iron/share/rmw_fastrtps_cpp/cmake)
-- Found FastRTPS: C:/dev/ros/iron/include
-- Using RMW implementation 'rmw_fastrtps_cpp' as default
-- Found sensor_msgs: 5.0.0 (C:/dev/ros/iron/share/sensor_msgs/cmake)
-- OpenCV ARCH: x64
-- OpenCV RUNTIME: vc16
-- OpenCV STATIC: OFF
-- Found OpenCV: C:/opencv (found suitable version "3.4.6", minimum required is "3") found components: opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs
-- Found OpenCV 3.4.6 in C:/opencv/x64/vc16/lib
-- You might need to add C:\opencv\x64\vc16\bin to your PATH to be able to run your applications.
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED - Success
-- Found ament_lint_auto: 0.14.1 (C:/dev/ros/iron/share/ament_lint_auto/cmake)
-- Found gtest sources under 'C:/dev/ros/iron/src/gtest_vendor': C++ tests using 'Google Test' will be built
[Processing: cv_bridge]
[Processing: cv_bridge]
[Processing: cv_bridge]
[Processing: cv_bridge]
....
[1h 1min 27.1s] [0/1 complete] [cv_bridge:cmake - 1h 1min 26.8s]
[Processing: cv_bridge]
...
```

And this is still compiling (1h34min). I stopped the process, compile again. The issue remains. Coclcon is running indefinitely. Could someone help me with this problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

While `cv_bridge` isn't in the core of the ros2 distribution for windows, you should be able to build it from source from the upstream repository here: https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv

I'm not sure what the situation is with the fork, but the ros-perception version should work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/workaround. I turned off the option "BUILD_TESTING" in the cmake file from the cv_bridge project and could compile without errors and without waiting during hours.

```
set(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
```

This is the result by running the command:

```
    λ colcon build --packages-up-to cv_bridge --event-handlers console_direct+
Starting >>> cv_bridge
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30152.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30152.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found ament_cmake_ros: 0.11.2 (C:/_dev/ros/iron/share/ament_cmake_ros/cmake)
-- Found Python3: C:/Python38/python.exe (found version "3.8.3") found components: Interpreter 
-- Found Python3: optimized;C:/Python38/libs/python38.lib;debug;C:/Python38/libs/python38_d.lib (found version "3.8.3") found components: Development NumPy Interpreter Development.Module Development.Embed 
-- Found Boost: C:/Boost/boost_1_76_0 (found version "1.76.0") found components: python38 
-- Found rclcpp: 21.0.4 (C:/_dev/ros/iron/share/rclcpp/cmake)
-- Found rosidl_generator_c: 4.0.1 (C:/_dev/ros/iron/share/rosidl_generator_c/cmake)
-- Found rosidl_generator_cpp: 4.0.1 (C:/_dev/ros/iron/share/rosidl_generator_cpp/cmake)
-- Using all available rosidl_typesupport_c: rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c;rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c
-- Using all available rosidl_typesupport_cpp: rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp;rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp
-- Found rmw_implementation_cmake: 7.1.0 (C:/_dev/ros/iron/share/rmw_implementation_cmake/cmake)
-- Found rmw_fastrtps_cpp: 7.1.2 (C:/_dev/ros/iron/share/rmw_fastrtps_cpp/cmake)
-- Found FastRTPS: C:/_dev/ros/iron/include  
-- Using RMW implementation 'rmw_fastrtps_cpp' as default
-- Found sensor_msgs: 5.0.0 (C:/_dev/ros/iron/share/sensor_msgs/cmake)
-- OpenCV ARCH: x64
-- OpenCV RUNTIME: vc16
-- OpenCV STATIC: OFF
-- Found OpenCV: C:/opencv (found suitable version "3.4.6", minimum required is "3") found components: opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs 
-- Found OpenCV 3.4.6 in C:/opencv/x64/vc16/lib
-- You might need to add C:\opencv\x64\vc16\bin to your PATH to be able to run your applications.
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED - Success
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/build/cv_bridge
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

[Processing: cv_bridge][cv_bridge:build - 30.0s]
  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule E:/_playground/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
  running egg_info
  creating cv_bridge.egg-info
  writing cv_bridge.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to cv_bridge.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to cv_bridge.egg-info\top_level.txt
  writing manifest file 'cv_bridge.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file 'cv_bridge.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  writing manifest file 'cv_bridge.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Building Custom Rule E:/_playground/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
  Building Custom Rule E:/_playground/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/CMakeLists.txt
  cv_bridge.cpp
  cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp
  rgb_colors.cpp
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(75,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::ROSCvMatContainer': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(132,3): message : see previous definition of '{ctor}' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(90,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::ROSCvMatContainer': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(136,3): message : see previous definition of '{ctor}' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(105,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::ROSCvMatContainer': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(140,3): message : see previous definition of '{ctor}' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(117,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::ROSCvMatContainer': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(148,3): message : see previous definition of '{ctor}' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(126,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::ROSCvMatContainer': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(156,3): message : see previous definition of '{ctor}' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(131,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::is_owning': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(166,3): message : see previous definition of 'is_owning' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(137,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::cv_mat': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(171,3): message : see previous definition of 'cv_mat' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(143,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::cv_mat': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(180,3): message : see previous definition of 'cv_mat' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(149,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::header': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(185,3): message : see previous definition of 'header' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(155,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::header': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(190,3): message : see previous definition of 'header' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(161,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::get_sensor_msgs_msg_image_pointer': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(195,3): message : see previous definition of 'get_sensor_msgs_msg_image_pointer' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(170,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::get_sensor_msgs_msg_image_pointer_copy': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(200,3): message : see previous definition of 'get_sensor_msgs_msg_image_pointer_copy' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(179,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::get_sensor_msgs_msg_image_copy': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(210,3): message : see previous definition of 'get_sensor_msgs_msg_image_copy' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(214,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::is_bigendian': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(215,3): message : see previous definition of 'is_bigendian' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp(220,1): warning C4273: 'cv_bridge::ROSCvMatContainer::encoding_override': inconsistent dll linkage [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp(220,3): message : see previous definition of 'encoding_override' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_bridge.hpp(57,1): warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'std::runtime_error' used as base for dll-interface class 'cv_bridge::Exception' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdexcept(101): message : see declaration of 'std::runtime_error' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_bridge.hpp(56): message : see declaration of 'cv_bridge::Exception' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_bridge.hpp(88,25): warning C4251: 'cv_bridge::CvImage::header': struct 'std_msgs::msg::Header_<std::allocator<void>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'cv_bridge::CvImage' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\_dev\ros\iron\include\std_msgs\std_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp(141): message : see declaration of 'std_msgs::msg::Header_<std::allocator<void>>' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_bridge.hpp(89,15): warning C4251: 'cv_bridge::CvImage::encoding': class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to 
be used by clients of class 'cv_bridge::CvImage' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(4871): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_bridge.hpp(90,11): warning C4251: 'cv_bridge::CvImage::image': class 'cv::Mat' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'cv_bridge::CvImage' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\opencv\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(801): message : see declaration of 'cv::Mat' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]       
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_bridge.hpp(149,31): warning C4251: 'cv_bridge::CvImage::tracked_object_': class 'std::shared_ptr<const void>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'cv_bridge::CvImage' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\..\include\cv_bridge/cv_bridge.hpp(149): message : see declaration of 'std::shared_ptr<const void>' (compiling source file E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp) [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp(396,49): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'sensor_msgs::msg::Image_<std::allocator<void>>::_step_type', possible loss of data [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp(548,87): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp(637,47): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp(639,43): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp(643,43): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp(692,61): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp(694,51): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.cpp(613,39): warning C4101: 'e': unreferenced local variable [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge.vcxproj]
     Creating library E:/_playground/vision_opencv/build/cv_bridge/src/Release/cv_bridge.lib and object E:/_playground/vision_opencv/build/cv_bridge/src/Release/cv_bridge.exp
  cv_bridge.vcxproj -> E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\Release\cv_bridge.dll
  Building Custom Rule E:/_playground/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/CMakeLists.txt
  module.cpp
  module_opencv4.cpp
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\module_opencv4.cpp(19,3): warning C4996: '_vsnprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online 
help for details. [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge_boost.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\module_opencv4.cpp(83,3): warning C5030: attribute 'gnu::unused' is not recognized [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge_boost.vcxproj]
E:\_playground\vision_opencv\cv_bridge\src\module_opencv4.cpp(89,3): warning C4996: '_vsnprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online 
help for details. [E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\cv_bridge_boost.vcxproj]
     Creating library E:/_playground/vision_opencv/build/cv_bridge/src/Release/cv_bridge_boost.lib and object E:/_playground/vision_opencv/build/cv_bridge/src/Release/cv_bridge_boost.exp
  cv_bridge_boost.vcxproj -> E:\_playground\vision_opencv\build\cv_bridge\src\boost\Release\cv_bridge_boost.pyd
  Building Custom Rule E:/_playground/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/environment/pythonpath.bat
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/environment/pythonpath.dsv
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge-3.4.0-py3.8.egg-info
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge-3.4.0-py3.8.egg-info/PKG-INFO
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge-3.4.0-py3.8.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge-3.4.0-py3.8.egg-info/top_level.txt
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge-3.4.0-py3.8.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge/__init__.py
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge/core.py
Listing 'E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge'...
Compiling 'E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge\\__init__.py'...
Compiling 'E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge\\core.py'...
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/lib/cv_bridge.lib
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/bin/cv_bridge.dll
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge/cv_bridge_export.h
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/Lib/site-packages/cv_bridge/boost/cv_bridge_boost.pyd
-- Up-to-date: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge
-- Up-to-date: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge/cv_bridge.hpp
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge/cv_mat_sensor_msgs_image_type_adapter.hpp
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge/rgb_colors.hpp
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge/visibility_control.h
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge/rgb_colors.h
-- Up-to-date: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/lib/cv_bridge.lib
-- Up-to-date: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/bin/cv_bridge.dll
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/ament_index/resource_index/package_run_dependencies/cv_bridge
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/ament_index/resource_index/parent_prefix_path/cv_bridge
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/environment/ament_prefix_path.bat
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/environment/ament_prefix_path.dsv
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/environment/path.bat
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/environment/path.dsv
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/local_setup.bat
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/local_setup.dsv
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/package.dsv
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/cv_bridge
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/cmake/export_cv_bridgeExport.cmake
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/cmake/export_cv_bridgeExport-release.cmake
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridge-extras.cmake
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/cmake/ament_cmake_export_targets-extras.cmake
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig-version.cmake
-- Installing: E:/_playground/vision_opencv/install/cv_bridge/share/cv_bridge/package.xml
Finished <<< cv_bridge [47.1s]

Summary: 1 package finished [47.7s]
```